# Can't get a jquery 'else if' to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here's the code snippet

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dmg = 60;
    var curr_hp = 1200;
    var tot_hp = 1200;
    $('#attk_spd').text('1.2 seconds');
    $('#dmg').text('60');
    $('#curr_hp').text('1200');
    $('#tot_hp').text('1200');

    var dps_timer;
    var attacking = 0;

    $("#btn").click(function () {
        if (dps_timer) {
            // We're already waiting for the next attack, so do nothing
            return;
        }

        $('#attk').text('You are currently attacking your target.');
        $('#btn').val('Retreat');

        var attack_once = function () {
            // Always attack immediately
            curr_hp -= dmg;
            $('#curr_hp').text(curr_hp);

            if (curr_hp > 0) {
                dps_timer = setTimeout(attack_once, 1200);
            } else if (attacking == 1) {
                clearTimeout(attack_once);
                attacking = 0;
                alert(attacking);
                $('#attk').text('You have retreated from battle.');
                $('#btn').val('Attack');
            } else {
                attacking = 0;
                alert(attacking);
                $('#attk').text('Your target has been destroyed.');
                $('#btn').val('Attack');
            }
        }
        if (attacking == 0) {
            attack_once();
            attacking = 1;
            alert(attacking);
        }
    });
});
```

I have alerts set up to check that the values are changing. This is basically a button click function. So when i click the button the first time the attacking starts and the button changes to retreat. However when i click retreat, the function should be executed again checking the conditionals, the attacking variable is set to 0 initially, changes to 1 when you click attack. So that if you click attack again it will run the second 'else if' conditional, but it doesn't. Help!

Code in action right here: http://www.evenstar-online.com/Jquery_snippets/dpsloop.php

Comment: Side question: have you heard of booleans?

Comment: if `curr_hp` is greater than 0 it will never hit your `else if`

Comment: Not the major issue but a problem nonetheless, passing `clearTimeout()` the name of the function won't do anything. You need to pass it the id of the timer, which you have as `dps_timer`.

Comment: @MattBall yes i actually set this up with booleans to start but in trying to get it to work i changed up everything that i could back and forth.

Comment: @MattBusche - `curr_hp` (1200) is being decreased by `dmg` (60) on every iteration, so it will become zero.

Comment: `attacking` will never be 1 when `attack_once` is called because your `if` requires it to be `0`.

Comment: Yes that's what it's suppose to do if you let it run straight through.

Comment: @MattBusche I'm **not** OP, but I ran his code under Chrome debugger.

Answer (score 0):

`attacking` can never be 1 when `attack_once` is called because your `if` statement requires it to be `0` to run.

```
if (attacking == 0) {
  //attacking is 0 when `attack_once()` is called
  attack_once();
  attacking = 1;
  alert(attacking);
}

var attack_once = function () {
  //.....
  // this can never be 1
  } else if (attacking == 1) {
```

Solution: Move your `attacking = 1` up above the `attack_once();` line

```
if (attacking == 0) {
  attacking = 1;
  attack_once();
  alert(attacking);
}
```

Comment: the solution being: you probably want to put the assignment first